# Why is arguments.callee.caller.name undefined?

Tags: javascript, arguments

How come this doesn't alert "http://127.0.0.1/sendRequest"? (Available at http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8Wd/52/)

```
var foo = {
    sendRequest: function() {
        alert(bar.getUrl());
    }
};                    

var bar = {
    getUrl: function() {
        return 'http://127.0.0.1/' + arguments.callee.caller.name;
    }
};

foo.sendRequest();
```

Comment: what you try to acheive ???????????

Comment: Because you have no function with name `sendRequest`, only anonymous functions.

Comment: Even if `callee` and `caller` come in quite handy sometimes, those are deprecated since ES5-strict. So I'd recommend not to use them anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a value in an object literal, as you're doing, doesn't affect the value at all.

```
var foo = {
    sendRequest: ...
```

The function value is only affected by the function expression, which doesn't contain a name.

```
             ... function() {
        alert(bar.getUrl());
    }
```

You need to include the name you want in the function expression itself <sup>[[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8Wd/53/)]</sup>.

```
var foo = {
    sendRequest: function sendRequest() {
```

Comment: Just be aware that you *may* run into issues using named function expressions in this way: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs

Answer (score 2):

If you do this:

```
var foo = {
    sendRequest: function() {
        alert(bar.getUrl());
    }
};                    

var bar = {
    getUrl: function() {
        return  arguments.callee;
    }
};

foo.sendRequest();
```

You will notice that the function doesn't have name which is true:

```
function() {
```

This is anonymous function.

You can name you method : `sendRequest: function myMethodName() {`

Answer (score 2):

Although the function is stored under the object property `foo.sendRequest`, and thus can be invoked via `foo.sendRequest()`, that function itself doesn't actually have a name. That's why `arguments.callee.caller.name` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function that is calling the function being called is an anonymous function (and hence, has no name).

Try:

```
function sendRequest() {
    alert(bar.getUrl());
}

var foo = {
    sendRequest: sendRequest
};                    

var bar = {
    getUrl: function() {
        return 'http://127.0.0.1/' + arguments.callee.caller.name;
    }
};

foo.sendRequest();
```