# Getting caller name in JS function

Tags: javascript

Please help me with below problem.

```
var test = new Object();
test.testInner = new Object();

test.testInner.main = function ()
{
   Hello();
}

function Hello()
{
  /**** Question: currently I am getting blank string with below code,
   **** Is there any way to get function name as "test.testInner.main" over here? */
  console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name);
}
test.testInner.main();
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this backtrace function: http://snipplr.com/view/23047/

Comment: Why are you trying to write the name of the caller to the log instead of using a debugger and looking at the stack trace?

Comment: I was asking *why* you wanted to do that, not if.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, Checked. It is not working.

Comment: @PhonicUK, Ah! Customer requirement. :)

Comment: Why does the customer require it?

Comment: @Quentin, Project is to make an SDK , Caller function will be from outside SDK, we need to log the caller name +  some more details in one log file.

Answer (score 1):

`test.testInner.main` has reference of `anonymous` (without name) function.
 You can get name by assigning name to them. modified code:

```
var test = new Object();
test.testInner = new Object();

test.testInner.main = function main()
{
   Hello();
}

function Hello()
{
  /**** Question: currently I am getting blank string with below code,
   **** Is there any way to get function name as "test.testInner.main" over here? */
  console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name);
}
test.testInner.main();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4TJeD/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the context of a function in Javascript.

```
function hello() { 
    console.log(this);
}
some.other.object = function() {
    hello.call(this, arguments, to, hello);
}
```

this will be some.other.object in hello().

In your example, the caller is main, and it doesn't have a name property because it is anonymous. Like here: [Why is arguments.callee.caller.name undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999485/why-is-arguments-callee-caller-name-undefined)

Besides, arguments is deprecated and should thus not be used.